# Using variable for asp.net repeater eval

Tags: asp.net, eval, repeater

I am new to `ASP.NET`

Can I use variable in eval in repeater? Or how can I use it?

For example:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, lngHome) %>
```

Code behind in form load:

```
if (session["dilKod"] == "eng")
 {
   lngHome = "eng_detail"
 }
 else
{
   lngHome = "tr_detail"
}
```

I have 2 fields in database table: `eng_detail` and `tr_detail`

So how can I use like this `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, lngHome) %>`?

Sorry for my poor English :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is `lngHome` a public property? Then you can just use:

`<%# lngHome %>`

Make sure you initialize `lngHome` with a default value or set it before databinding occurs. So move this to `Page_init` instead:

```
if (session["dilKod"] == "eng")
 {
   lngHome = "eng_detail"
 }
 else
{
   lngHome = "tr_detail"
}
```

Comment: <%#lngHome%> will work also inside a control if lngHome is public

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, `lngHome` should be public global field of the class, for example:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   public string lngHome  = "someDefaultValue";
   ...
```